# Creating variable for association in ruby on rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a set up where **Goals** have **Steps** and **Steps** have **Tasks**.  In my view I am showing a goal, if that goal has steps then I can pull those and show them as well.  I am having  a hard time showing the tasks for each individual step now.  I can get the task associated with the proper step so part of this is working, but I cannot access any of the data, **name** and **description** specifically for the task.

I am just unsure how to create this in the controller.  I have cruised around [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) trying to find a solution and tried things like

```
 @goal.steps.tasks 
 @step.tasks
```

I just cannot find anything that clicks for creating the variable in the controller so I can access it.

goals_controller.rb show method

```
def show
  @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
  @steps = @goal.steps(page: params[:page])
  # @tasks = ?
end
```

goal.rb

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :steps, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tasks, through: :steps
end
```

step.rb

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :goals
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
 end
```

task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :steps
end
```

views

goals/show view

```
  <p>
    <% if @goal.steps.any? %>

        <!-- Projects Row -->
          <div class="row">
            <%= render @steps %> 
          </div>
        <!-- /.row -->


      <% else %>
      No steps for this goal.
    <% end %>
  </p>
```

the partial rendered for the steps

```
<div id="steps-<%= step.id %>" class="col-md-3 portfolio-item not completed" style="background-color:#e26a5c;border-radius:10px;border:1px solid #6cbdc4;margin:0 5px 5px 0;">
    <h3>
        <p>In order to achieve this goal I need to <strong><%= step.name %></strong> in <strong><%= time_ago_in_words(step.deadline) %></strong></p>
    </h3>
    <a href="/steps/<%= step.id %>/edit" style="background: none;"><img src="/img/icon-edit.png"></a>


<% if step.tasks.any? %>

    <%= render "tasks/task" %>

<% else %>

<%end %>
 </div>
 <% else %>

<div id="steps-<%= step.id %>" class="col-md-3 portfolio-item completed" style="background-color:#6cbdc4;border-radius:10px;border:1px solid #e26a5c;margin:0 5px 5px 0;">
    <h3>
        <p>In an effort to achieve this goal I needed to <strong><%= step.name %></strong> in <strong><%= time_ago_in_words(step.deadline) %></strong></p>
    </h3>
    <a href="/steps/<%= step.id %>/edit" style="background: none;"><img src="/img/icon-edit.png"></a>
</div>
```

Tasks/task is the partial I am trying to pull in, I can link to it on the correct step and everything, but it says undefined method when I put **task.name** or **task.description** in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `goals_controller.rb`:

```
def show
  @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
  @steps = @goal.steps(page: params[:page]).includes(:tasks)
end
```

Then in your view you could have something like this:

```
<ul>
  <% @steps.each do |step| %>
    <li>
      <%= step %>
      <p>Tasks:</p>
      <ul>
        <% step.tasks.each do |task| %>
          <li><%= task %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

For more info on `includes`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: I added my view code, I am rendering partials if there are steps, and also if those steps have tasks,  The error I get is undefined method when I add "task.name" for example.  Even pasting in the view code you gave me got that error.

Comment: Sounds like you are having issues deeper than view/controller code. To make sure you environment is in good shape, open up your rails console and try running the following one liner: `Goal.all.includes(:steps => :tasks).each{|goal| goal.steps.each{|step| step.tasks.each{|task| puts "Task.name = #{task.name}"}}}`. You should get a bunch of task names as a result. If not, make sure your database and associations are set up properly.

Comment: Well that certainly narrows it down.  Check your `tasks` table in the database and make sure you have `name` column.  Check your migrations and `db/schema.rb`.